# If-Statement Not Refreshing for Toggle-On, Toggle-Off

Tags: ios, swift, if-statement, toggle

It's a basic method with an if statement based around a toggle being on or off. If the toggle is off, it calculates, and when I turn the toggle on and add the second amount, it calculates, but if I switch the toggle after, it won't refresh and calculate as "toggle off". I tried reloading the data, but it's not really budging. Any advice?

Thanks

```
   if tipSlider == false {
        totalMealCost.text = "$\(doubleCost)"
    } else {
        let tipValue = Float(tipSlider.value / 100)
        let roundedTip = (round(100*tipValue)/100)

        let tipCost = roundedTip  * doubleCost
        let roundedTipCost = (round(100*tipCost)/100)

        let fullCost = doubleCost + roundedTipCost
        let roundedFullCost = (round(100*fullCost)/100)
        totalMealCost.text = "$\(roundedFullCost)"
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Comment: have you shown your tried code

Comment: It's because your conditions never set a new value for the tipSlider. If they're set somewhere else, then please show us that code, too.